# PHP arsort issue with keys

Tags: php

```
$vals = array(51, 23, 77, 3, 8, 31, 17, 102, 87);
arsort($vals);
```

From here, how can I get the keys of the 3 first values? If I do `$vals[0]` it won't work because it'll return me the original [0] key before the arsort.

I want to get the original keys of 102, 87 and 77 after arsort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you need it for, one way is

```
$keys = array_keys($vals);
```

$keys[0] will contain the first key.
$vals[$keys[0]] will contain the first value.

An alternate way

```
$part = array_slice($vals, 0, 3, true);
```

$part will contain three $key => $value pairs for the first three entries.

And for the first three keys, you can mix and match the above, such as:

```
$firstThree = array_keys(array_slice($vals, 0, 3, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$firstThreeKeys = array_slice(array_keys($vals), 0, 3);

echo join(', ', $firstThreeKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a method, maybe not the best however:

```
reset($arr); $key1=key($arr);
next($arr); $key2=key($arr);
next($arr); $key3=key($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_keys()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)?

Alternatively, loop through the sorted array with a `foreach` and you can still get the keys:

```
$i = 0;
$numKeysToGet = 3;
$keys = array();
foreach ($vals as $k => $v) if ($i < $numKeysToGet) {
  $keys[] = $k;
  $i++;
} else break;

// $keys now contains the first three array keys
```

Answer (score 0):

arsort saves key=>value relationship, so it's usualy used for associative arrays (hash). For your needs try to sort value=>key array instead of your key=>value with the standart sotring function. Otherwise you can use foreach loop (limit it with 3 iterations) to get the keys.